# model = keras.models.load_model(model_file) kills kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, keras, model, jupyter-notebook

Every time I try to load my model file the kernel dies and has to restart. Absolutely no idea what to do here.

```
model_file = cur_dir+model_names[i]

print(model_file)
```

Output: /home/jack/Desktop/output/models/2019-09-27 00-05-20/02-val_acc-0.69-val_loss-0.66.hdf5

```
model = keras.models.load_model(model_file)
```

Then the kernel dies.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe your model size of too large to be loaded into your RAM.

Comment: I try to load DenseNet201 model and it consume 95%+ of my 24GB ram. Maybe memory issue.